# Generating rigging problem

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

[image]

Im trying to generate rig my character yet for some reason the rest of my generate rig for the body isnt appearing. Does this only work when it comes to the human meta rig?

Comment: "Does this only work when it comes to the human meta rig?" What?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you follow the Rigify bone naming conventions, the rig widgets should generate. As it looks like you're creating your own custom rig, I recommend you read through the [Rigify documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html) so you understand how the addon works.